# How to change bibstyle features?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to manipulate a certain bibstyle, i.e. "plaindin".

The result I get from the original plaindin is, e.g.

[10] HAGENMEYER, V. ; DELALEAU, E.: Exact Feedforward Linearization Based on
Differential Flatness. In: International Journal of Control 76 (2003), Nr. 6, S. 537–556

However, I would like to have the following:

[HD03] HAGENMEYER, V. ; DELALEAU, E.: Exact Feedforward Linearization Based on
Differential Flatness. In: International Journal of Control 76 (2003), Nr. 6, p. 537–556

So I would like to make two changes to "plaindin":

1) Numbering/citation reference from [10] to [HD03]
2) Abbreviation for pages from german "S." to english "p."

How can I most easily obtain the desired result?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Don't you look for a style like `alpha.bst`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I believe alpha does the numerical numbering [1], [2], ... and so on where I would like [KD13], [Pfe02], [HFK10] and so on....

Also, alpha lists authors like A. Familyname where I would like FAMILYNAME, A.

Comment: alphadin does pretty much what I want, except that it refers to pages as "S." where I need "p."

Comment: The reason behind this is very very simple: `plaindin` is a german style for numerical citations.

Comment: Modern system `biblatex` is highly customizable. That might be an alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - for me, it's too late to change my system, though :-/ And yes, I am aware of this being a special problem for german style.

Comment: If `alphadin.bst` works for you, then just make a copy of it and change the function that formats the pages. But there's lots of other German in it too. Would that all need to be changed?  (Not that hard either.)